# Can I manuall set the stageResult in Jenkins without using the catchError function?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've seen plenty of examples setting the stageResult value in Jenkins using catchError, like so...

```
catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', message: 'This stage is allowed to fail', stageResult: 'SUCCESS') {
    sh mycmd
}
```

But can the stageResult value be set without using this function? For example, the build result can be set using `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'`. Does something similar exist for stageResult?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?